# How to protect vimeo videos on my site and allow specific authenticated users to see it?

Tags: video-streaming, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm working on social network people are allowed to upload videos and only friends can see it

I'm thinking about using vimeo pro but not sure and how can I manage who can see the video so only user friends will be allowed not all my system users

Comment: Have you found another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. [The API can only toggle existing Vimeo video privacy settings](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042878091-Custom-video-privacy-overriding-privacy-settings-using-the-API).